# Automapper Mapping of simple object to more complex nested type

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, automapper-6

I am in the process of a refactor and utilizing AutoMapper (6.2.1) to help us in formatting of API returns that conform to a specific contract. The DTO objects we are using internally are meant to simplify our understanding of the data before returning the data in the more complex type.

The Issue:
I have a DTO with a `List<T>` where I need one of the properties of `<T>` to be mapped to the collection in the more complex type. This is actually pretty straight forward but the problem is, what if the collection I am trying to map to in the more complex type is in fact inside another "higher" collection. Essentially I am in a little bit of a collection inside a collection problem.

Ex: DTO

```
public class ItemDTO
{
   List<ItemDescriptionDTO> ItemDescriptions { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDescriptionDTO
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

More Complex object I need to map to and do not have control over

```
public class ComplexThing // This is the object I need (It's ugly, I hate it too)
{
    public ComplexItemDescriptions { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexItemDescriptions 
{
    public List<ComplexItemDescription> ComplexItemDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexItemDescription
{
    public UnparsedItemDescriptions UnparsedItemDescriptions { get; set; }
}

public class UnparsedItemDescriptions
{
    public List<UnparsedItemDescription> UnparsedItemDescription { get; set; }
}

public class UnparsedItemDescription
{
    public string UnparsedItemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

In essence I need to take the `Description` in my simple `ItemDescriptionDTO`and map that through this awful chain of nested objects to set the `UnparsedItemDescription`

I am able to properly map from `UnparsedItemDescription` all the way to the `ComplexItemDescription` but going higher than that to the `Complex` thing is giving me some trouble.

This is the mapping I have so far:

```
config.CreateMap<ItemDescriptionDTO, UnparsedItemDescription>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UnparsedItemDescription, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Description));

config.CreateMap<ItemDTO, UnparsedItemDescriptions>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UnparsedItemDescription, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.ItemDescritpions));

config.CreateMap<ItemDTO, ComplexItemDescription>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.UnparsedItemDescriptions.UnparsedItemDescription, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.ItemDescriptions));

// This is where we start failing (I think I am just not understanding something fundamental to how Automapper does things or I am up against some silly edge case
config.CreateMap<ItemDTO, ComplexItemDescriptions>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ComplexItemDescription, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.ItemDescriptions));
```

I need the `ComplexThing` because there are other properties in that class that are returned so I can't just get away with returning say a `ComplexItemDescription`

I would appreciate an assistance you could give. I admittedly have a base understanding on how Automapper works (which I am in the process of trying to get better at) but this is really throwing me at the moment.

Comment: But it seems there is no unique mapping from ItemDTO to ComplexThing. Suppose you have 4 `ItemDescriptions` in ItemDTO. This can be mapped to 4 ComplexItemDescription each with 1 UnparsedItemDescription, or to 2 ComplexItemDescription each with 2 UnparsedItemDescription, and so on.